# Подключение камеры видеонаблюдения к сайту

Tags: javascript, html5

Всем привет, есть сайт на опенкарт, к нему нужно привязать камеру видеонаблюдения, чтоб через сайт можно было просматривать что пишет эта камера в онлайн режиме. Каким образом можно такое сделать?

Answer (score 0):

На сайте ставишь ffmpeg. Ffmeg запускаешь на входе rtp с камеры, на выходе hls. Получтся плэйлист и кучка фрагментов. Плэйлист на сайт в любой html5 плеер.